# makefile extension

Tags: makefile

I wanted to create a makefile. So I wrote instructions in a notepad file.
But what extension should I give while saving this file?

Comment: Answer by @user93353 may be related: [My ESP is telling me that you are trying to create it using notepad.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019964/367456)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you run:

```
make
```

this program will look for a file named makefile in your directory, and then execute it.
If you have several makefiles, then you can execute them with the command:

```
make -f MyMakefile
```

Comment: So, to clarify: makefiles normally do not have an extension, not even a dot at the end.

Comment: Correct, or you can save with a file extension and point make to it using the -f switch.

Comment: When I create makefile by notepad, it is saved as text document and
when I type make on command line, it shows makefile not found.
When I create makefile by ed editor, it is saved as file type which
is found by make.

Comment: are you sure you are working on same directory. simply gedit makefile and paste your code here and run on the shell, make.

Comment: Notepad will generally supply a .txt extension. Notepad is also not the most friendly editor for coding. Editor choice is essentially a religious argument, and there are a lot to choose among. Notepad, however, will appear near the bottom of most people's lists. On Windows, be sure to disable the "feature" that hides file extensions in Explorer to avoid even more confusion.

Comment: I was having the same problem on Windows with Notepad++ and the file extension. To solve, I saved as type All types (".") from the drop down list and it got rid of the extension. It now works (in Cygwin).

Comment: @AndrewMcGregor's comment answers the question better than the accepted answer itself.

Comment: Just get Vim *holy war begins*

Comment: The common extension to use with Makefiles is .mk. If you have multiple makefiles, use the .mk extension

Answer (score 14):

By default, The GNU Make tries some particular names, no using any extension. You can specify file with any name to it. But if you want syntax highlighting in some editors, you can use an extension.

There is a wildcard rule for recognizing make files in Geany editor:

```
Make=*.mak;*.mk;GNUmakefile;makefile;Makefile;makefile.*;Makefile.*;
```

Answer (score 9):

From the GNU Make [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

> By default, when make looks for the
>   makefile, it tries the following
>   names, in order: `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`
>   and `Makefile`. Normally you should call
>   your makefile either `makefile` or
>   `Makefile`

These will be searched for if you don't specify the makefile with the `-f` flag (Only GNU make will look for `GNUMakefile`, so give it that name only if you know you're using GNU tools)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you're running Windows, in which case makefiles often have a `.NMK` suffix (because they are intended for use with `NMAKE`). In the civilised world though makefiles do not generally have a suffix: `makefile` or `Makefile` are the canonical file names.

Comment: "In a civilses world" I see where you are going with that. Unfortunately, I am using Makefile in Windows, still.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to distinguish one from another, and you are configuration managing the makefile, you should use project.make as the name. On the basis that most LSE's , in particular gedit, are recognising this over .mak.  Upon packaging, or sign out to a dedicated folder it can be renamed to makefile, the fully qualified path being descriptive of the project. In this way you can have different versions. If your work is complex enough to be using a makefile you should not mixing multiple builds in the same folder anyway.