# Extension-less File in Windows with Notepad

Tags: windows, notepad

How to create a file with no file extension using Windows Notepad?

When I tried to create a file with Notepad in Windows, then the file automatically saved as a text file (*.txt).

I then tried setting the "Save as type" field to "All files (*.*)", but no success.

I even tried on the command prompt as well

```
C:\My Documents> notepad myheader
```

But then Notepad creates a file called `C:\My Documents\myheader.txt`.

Comment: What's preventing you from simply creating the file without an extension?

Comment: why don't you try ? is there anything stopping you ? have you any trouble ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want a file without an extension?

Comment: when I tried to create a file file with notepad in Windows, then the file automatically saved as text file.I even tried by setting the "Save as type" field to "All files".But doesn't work.is there way?

Comment: @biraj bora: Just rename your file by removing the extension?

Comment: @ DBRalir, Stephane, Thomas , Haroogan : Thank you all for your concern. I got it now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My extrasensory perception (ESP) is telling me that you are trying to create it using Windows Notepad.

That is (I.e.):

```
C:\My Documents> notepad myheader
```

And Windows Notepad creates a file called "`myheader.txt`".

You can do

```
C:\My Documents> notepad myheader.
```

*(Note the dot after "myheader".)*

This creates a file without a file extension on Windows and with Windows Notepad.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Windows 10.  I was unable to figure out a way to create a file without an extension using just the command prompt.  I was able to open a file that didn't and re-save it but I was not able to create one.

Comment: I just tried it on Windows10 & it did work for me.

Comment: strange.  did you do it with the full path or just the filename?  I was trying it with a file path before the file name.  It always seems to add .txt or ..txt or something stupid.

Comment: I just opened a command line & did "notepad abc."

Comment: @user93353 yes, this also worked for me!!

Comment: is this an LLM?

Comment: @Kaii is what an LLM?